# How to align a Column's child to the bottom in container in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using Column in container component in flutter,now I want the row component to align the button, this is my code:

```
return Container(
        color: Theme
            .of(context)
            .scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onHorizontalDragStart: _onHorizontalDragStart,
          onHorizontalDragUpdate: _onHorizontalDragUpdate,
          onHorizontalDragEnd: _onHorizontalDragEnd,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
              16.0,
            ),
            child:Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () => launchUrl(item.link),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text(
                        item.title == "" ? "Comment" : item.title,
                        style: Theme
                            .of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .headline5
                            .copyWith(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                if (item.domain != "")
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                    child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () async {
                          Channel channel = await Repo.fetchChannelItem(int.parse(item.subSourceId));
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChannelPage(item:channel)),
                              //ProfilePage(username: item.author))
                        );
                      }, child: Text(
                      item.domain,
                      style: Theme
                          .of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .caption,
                      )
                    ),
                  ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              ProfilePage(username: item.author)),
                    );
                  },
                  child: RichText(
                    text: TextSpan(
                      children: <TextSpan>[
                        TextSpan(
                          text: item.author,
                          style: Theme
                              .of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .caption
                              .copyWith(
                            color: Theme
                                .of(context)
                                .primaryColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                        TextSpan(
                          text: " ${String.fromCharCode(8226)} ",
                          style: Theme
                              .of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .caption,
                        ),
                        TextSpan(
                          text: item.ago,
                          style: Theme
                              .of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .caption,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                if (item.content != "")
                  Html(
                    data: item.content,
                    style: {
                      "body": Style(
                        fontSize: FontSize(19.0),
                      ),
                    },
                    onLinkTap: (url) => launchUrl(url),
                  ),
                if (item.parts.isNotEmpty)
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: item.parts.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return PartSnippet(part: parts[index]);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          if(item.isFav == 1)
                            IconButton(
                              icon:Icon(Feather.bookmark,
                                  color: Theme
                                  .of(context)
                                  .primaryColor),
                              onPressed: () => touchFav("unfav"),
                            ),
                          if(item.isFav != 1)
                            IconButton(
                            icon:Icon(Feather.bookmark,
                                color: Theme
                                .of(context)
                                .primaryColor),
                            onPressed: () => touchFav("fav"),
                            ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "${item.score}",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: Theme
                                  .of(context)
                                  .textTheme
                                  .caption
                                  .copyWith(
                                color: Theme
                                    .of(context)
                                    .primaryColor,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            Feather.arrow_up,
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "${item.score}",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: Theme
                                  .of(context)
                                  .textTheme
                                  .caption
                                  .copyWith(
                                color: Theme
                                    .of(context)
                                    .primaryColor,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            Feather.message_square,
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              item.descendants.toString(),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: Theme
                                  .of(context)
                                  .textTheme
                                  .caption,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Feather.share_2,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () =>
                      handleShare(
                          id: item.id,
                          title: item.title,
                          postUrl: item.link),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: new RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      print('');
                    },
                    color: const Color(0xfff1c232),
                    child: new Text(''),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
```

the container shows some article content, then some icon's like `like\upvote\share` in the button, but sometimes the article content is very short, now I want the `like\upvote\share` icon align the button of screen, not in the middle of screen, what should I do to make it? I am trying using Expand but do not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to align every `child` of the `Column` at the bottom use:

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
```

if you want to align only the last Widget of the `Column` I would place a `Spacer()` before the last Widget:

```
Column(
  children: [
    FirstWidget,
    SecondWidget,
    Spacer(), //use this widget to take the available space
    LastWidget,
  ],
),
```

Comment: spacer show this error: `RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.`@Nuqo

Comment: like the error says, you have to give your container a constraint, e.g. height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, if you want to give it the height of the screen.

Comment: Works, Thank you for saving my time.@Nuqo

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the widget which is right above your Row wrap it inside an Expanded widget and give it a flex =1